# SQL Server 2012 Group By with values in single query

Tags: sql-server

Trying to see if this is possible in one select statement using SQL Server 2012.

Table is this:

**Orders**:

```
Order_Index Audit_ID
--------------------
101           CB
102           MM
103           CN
```

`Audit_ID` CB and CN are the same person and MM should be excluded from results so I am trying to show something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN Audit_Id IN ('CB’, ’CN’) 
          THEN 'Cindy’ 
          ELSE Audit_Id 
    END AS Audit_Id, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Order_Index) AS ‘Total Orders’
FROM
    Orders 
WHERE 
    Audit_Id IN ('CB', 'CN’)
GROUP BY
    Audit_Id
```

Result:

```
Audit_Id    Total Orders
-------------------------    
Cindy           1
Cindy           1
```

Desired result:

```
Audit_Id    Total Orders
-------------------------    
Cindy           2
```

Is that result possible in a single query?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012 R2** version - only **2012** - fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all your results are apparently in the same group, the whole `group by` clause is really unnecessary here:

```
select 'Cindy' as "Audit ID", count(*) as "Total Orders"
from Orders
where Audit_Id in ('CB','CN');
```

Now if what you're really trying to accomplish is some kind of "custom" grouping, you were probably shooting for something more like this:

```
select
    case when Audit_ID in ('A', 'B') then 'Group1' ... else Audit_ID end as "Audit ID",
    count(*) as "Total Orders"
from Orders
group by case when Audit_ID in ('A', 'B') then 'Group1' ... else Audit_ID end;
```

You have to duplicate the expression between the `group by` and the `select` list unless you just nest the expression in another reference like a derived table or CTE.